# How to make nested list based on condition

Tags: python

Input list:

```
[[0, 78], [0, 118], [1, 198], [1, 78], [0, 118], [0, 198], [1, 434], [1, 514], [1, 434]]
```

How to group sub-lists of a list based on the first element of the nested lists. If the first element value is 0, a new list should be formed with all the sub-lists until the next 0 value.

The idea is to group sub-lists in nested lists.

The desired output should be like this:

Output:

```
[[[0, 78], [0, 118], [1, 198], [1, 78]], [[0, 118], [0, 198], [1, 434], [1, 514], [1, 434]]]
```

Comment: The output list doesn't match your condition...

Comment: What would the output look like if the first sub-list does **not** start with zero?

Comment: For me the value 0 is like a trigger value.

Comment: Ok so the first element is `[0, 78]` -> 0 is the first value. However, the second element is `[0, 118]` why wouldn't it start a new sub-list? It should start a new sub-list according to your condition.

Comment: You are right I did not specified. Just the first occurrence it is the checked value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one:

```
lol = [[0, 78], [0, 118], [1, 198], [1, 78], [0, 118], [0, 198], [1, 434], [1, 514], [1, 434]]
flag = False
output = [[]] if lol[0][0] else []

for t in lol:
    if t[0] == 0:
        if not flag:
            output.append([])
            flag = True
    else:
        flag = False
    output[-1].append(t)

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[0, 78], [0, 118], [1, 198], [1, 78]], [[0, 118], [0, 198], [1, 434], [1, 514], [1, 434]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) the first item in each sublist and then *"merge"* every two groups by [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)ing them:

```py
from itertools import groupby, chain

l = [[0, 78], [0, 118], [1, 198], [1, 78], [0, 118], [0, 198], [1, 434], [1, 514], [1, 434]]
temp = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(l, lambda sub: sub[0])]
print(temp)
res = [list(chain.from_iterable(temp[i:i+2])) for i in range(0, len(temp), 2)]
print(res)
```

Gives:

```
[[[0, 78], [0, 118]], [[1, 198], [1, 78]], [[0, 118], [0, 198]], [[1, 434], [1, 514], [1, 434]]]
[[[0, 78], [0, 118], [1, 198], [1, 78]], [[0, 118], [0, 198], [1, 434], [1, 514], [1, 434]]]
```

Comment: @AlainT. Indeed. Changed it to use `chain` and slicing instead of indexing so this case will not fail. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score -1):

You could do this by extending the resulting list based on the last entry's initial item:

```
L = [[0, 78], [0, 118], [1, 198], [1, 78], [0, 118], [0, 198], [1, 434], 
     [1, 514], [1, 434]]

R = []
R.extend([s] for s in L if not R or R[-1][-1][0] > s[0] or R[-1].append(s))

print(R)

[[[0, 78], [0, 118], [1, 198], [1, 78]],
 [[0, 118], [0, 198], [1, 434], [1, 514], [1, 434]]]
```